# Why can I set a hash attribute without having attr_writer?

Tags: ruby, attributes

If I understand it correctly, Ruby allows to set instance attributes only if they are declared as writable (e.g. via `attr_writer`, `attr_accessor`, or a custom setter method). I have noticed that I can set a hash attribute without having an explicit writer method:

```
class HashSetter
  attr_reader :hash

  def initialize
    @hash = {}
  end

  def set_hash
    self.hash[:message] = 'haha'
  end
end

obj = HashSetter.new
obj.set_hash
puts obj.hash
# -> {:message=>"haha"}
```

As expected, the same code wouldn't work if I were to have a "regular" variable instead of a hash:

```
class VarSetter
  attr_reader :var

  def initialize
    @var = nil
  end

  def set_var
    self.var = 10
  end
end

obj = VarSetter.new
obj.set_var
# ->
# check_accessors.rb:26:in `set_var': undefined method `var=' for #<VarSetter:0x00000001cba510 @var=nil> (NoMethodError)
```

Why am I allowed to set the `:hash` attribute in the first piece of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example you're not setting the `hash` attribute, you are actually getting the attribute (using the attribute reader) and call the `[]=` method on it. What you are not allowed to do without an `attr_writer` is to assign directly to `self.hash`, i.e. you can't write `self.hash = {}`, this is why you get an error in the second example.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks! Do you know if there's a way to protect the data accessed via `attr_reader` from being written to?

Comment: Not sure if it's what you need, but you may want to take a look at [`Object#freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-freeze).

Comment: @sakovias you could freeze the hash or you could return a copy

Comment: @sakovias, Are you aware that despite all the suggestion, anyone can write:  `my_hash_setter.instance_variable_set(:@hash, 10)` ?  Ruby doesn't prevent a programmer who really wants to from violating encapsulation.

Comment: @7stud: thanks for letting me know. Yes, this looks like the Ruby way of breaking barriers.

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand it correctly, Ruby allows to set instance attributes only if they are declared as writable

You misunderstand. `attr_writer :foo` is just syntactic sugar for:

```
def foo=(value)
  @foo = value
end
```

which then allows you to call `object.foo = :bar`, which invokes the `foo=` method with `:bar` as the parameter.

You can always assign an instance variable, regardless of `attr_writer` declarations.

Comment: The op's code doesn't really do what the op describes.  The code does not directly set an @variable--instead it looks like it uses a setter method, `self.hash =` so your answer  doesn't address the the real issue in the question.  See toro2k's answer.

Comment: That's why I said "instance attributes" rather than an "instance variable" in the quote above :) I'd like to protect the instance variables being assigned directly by using `attr_writer` wrappers.

Comment: @sakovias, Are you aware that despite all the suggestion, anyone can write:  `my_hash_setter.instance_variable_set(:@hash, 10)` ?